# make jackson serialize set as list

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

On my server side I use Hibernate to retrieve data to Set , I don't want to use List on server side.

I'm using @OrderBy annotation, so my sets are ordered on server.

However, when I send my data to browser, and parse JSON my sets become unordered in javascript.
Can I somehow configure jackson ObjectMapper, or use some annotation to serialize my Sets as Lists ?

It only needs to change {} to [] in

I know I can create another DTO, but that's a lot of boilerplate.

Is there some flag or annotation that could trigger such behaviour?

EDIT:

let's say I've got:

{"a","b","c","d"}

on server side produced by my code, and that's sent to browser. 
browser would receive same content, but when I evaluate it (eval(...)),
browser don't treat that as string, but as map.

And when I iterate that map it's unordered.

If browser would receive array, that is:

["a","b","c","d"]

after evaluation in browser it would still be sorted;

I want JACKSON to just use [] instead of {} for sets.

Hope I'm more clear now

Comment: A set will be serialized as a array not as an object, so there is some other problem

Comment: Are you sure, yours set is really sorted? I sometimes serialize TreeSet and I always have sorted data after serialization. Check how serialization works with Hibernate's implementations of "sorted set". Could you provide an example, how it looks?

Comment: `However, when I send my data to browser, and parse JSON my sets become unordered in javascript` - are you sure the order is not being lost *after* the conversion to JS? Did you print out the data you received on the client side, before parsing it into an object?

Comment: yes, order is lost after conversion to js, and I want to keep my order by using array instead, is that doable ?